# declaring a template member function return type

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a simple traits function:

```
template <typename Traits>
struct Cal {
    typedef typename Traits::T T;
    static T f(T a, T b);
};

struct FTraits {
    typedef float T;
};
struct DTraits {
    typedef double T;
};
```

I can think of 4 ways to implement `Cal::f` and specify the return type.

```
// option 1. compile. as inline implementation
template <typename Traits>
struct Cal {
    typedef typename Traits::T T;
    static T f(T a, T b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};
// option 2. compile
template <typename Traits>
typename Traits::T Cal<Traits>::f(T a, T b) {
    return a+b;
};
// option 3. does not compile
template <typename Traits>
T Cal<Traits>::f(T a, T b) {
    return a+b;
};
// option 4. compile
template <typename Traits>
auto Cal<Traits>::f(T a, T b) -> T {
    return a+b;
};
```

I believe option 4 is added in c++11 as option 3 is not possible in the previous standard. My question is, why option 3 does not work? Specifically, I wonder the reason behind that return type T cannot name a type, whereas argument type T can name a type. Does compiler work in different contexts for return and argument types? Also, why c++11 choose option 4 over option 3? It seems option 3 is more intuitive than option 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even compilers of a sophisticated language like C++ still need to process the file from the beginning to the end.

If the declaration after `template< … >` begins with `T`, the compiler needs to know what `T` is, in order to parse it and determine that it's a return type, before proceeding to find the rest of the declaration.

Essentially, the qualifier `Cal< Traits >::` needs to come syntactically before any unqualified uses of members of `Cal`. It's much easier to extend the language with trailing return types, which place `Cal< Traits >::` immediately after `auto`, than to create a heuristic for skipping over type names with unknown identifiers.

Comment: So the return type is hard to deduce, because it is specified before function signature and body. In c++11, trailing return types can be easily deducible, because it is specified after function signature. Am I correct? Yet, I remember that C++ uses LALR, thus be able to see one token ahead - which is function signature for return type case. Then is it technically possible to implement in that way (surely it'll be still hard)?

Comment: @xosp7tom C++ isn't completely defined by the grammar rules listed in its standardization; it only has EBNF with context-dependent semantic rules for productions formed from identifiers. Some compilers are "modified" LALR. In your example, one token of lookahead would suffice, but that's not the general case. By the way, deduction is something else; there is no deduction at all in your example program.

Answer (score 0):

T is a typedef inside the Cal class template. It isn't defined at global scope. The following should work fine as option 3:

```
template <typename Traits>
typename Cal<Traits>::T Cal<Traits>::f(T a, T b) {
    return a+b;
};
```